# Get the Keras Sequential Model out of a local minimum

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, image-classification

I am using Keras to tell the difference between background and signal.

> [A Background Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tORkT.png)
> [A Second Background Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsEsD.png)
> [A Signal Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5f3e.png)

The model used here is

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(472,696)),#flatten the data
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),#decide how many neurons to use
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')])#how many classes you have

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My training is

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=6)#train with data
```

Often I just get a local minimum with accuracy approximately as 0.5.

> Epoch 1/6 -
> loss: 45.3655 - accuracy: 0.4833

> Epoch 2/6 -
> loss: 0.6934 - accuracy: 0.4855

> Epoch 3/6 -
> loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4959

> Epoch 4/6 -
> loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5145

> Epoch 5/6 -
> loss: 0.6930 - accuracy: 0.5145

> Epoch 6/6 -
> loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.5145

Am I using the correct model?

I have tried to change the acitivation from "relu" to "LeakyReLU" and change optimizer to "sgd". But no significant improvement.

Comment: You do not know if its a local minimum or not, and the activation at the output should be softmax, not sigmoid.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks! If the loss doesn't change, does it not mean it's a local minimum? Also, I have changed the output layer and the result is improving already!

Answer (score 0):

You need to experiment to see if its a local minimum or not. Add/remove layers, change number of neurons. Also use validation data to see if loss decreases do you overfit or not.